# Parse dag fail cannot found module slackclient on Cloud Composer

Tags: airflow, google-cloud-composer

I create a cloud composer on GCP, and add a dag on it.
But web server shows it `No module named 'slackclient'`, I add pypi `slackclient==2.0.1` from Cloud Composer UI.
It still not working.

How could I fix this issue??

Here is my dag below,

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add the following to your `requirements.txt`:

`requirements.txt`:

```
slackclient>=1.0.0,<2.0.0
```

The one you are installing is >2.0 which is not compatible with Slack Hooks/Operators.

Run the following `gcloud` command replacing `ENVIRONMENT-NAME` & `LOCATION`:

```
gcloud composer environments update ENVIRONMENT-NAME \\
--update-pypi-packages-from-file requirements.txt \\
--location LOCATION
```